# What are the disadvantages of writing an Express.js application wiith TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I wonder what the disadvantages would be if one decides to write Express.js applications or APIs with TypeScript, instead of JavaScript.

Comment: Can you describe some disadvantages of TS over JS in general?

Comment: @axiac the only so-called "disadvantage" I can think of is that TS should be compiled to JS. For this reason I wonder why most Node.js and Express apps I can see on the Internet are written in JS, instead of TS. So I thought that there's something crucial that I am missing.

Comment: The compiling step happens only once, offline, and it runs pretty fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only **objective**, non-opinion-based disadvantage I can come up with is that you have to compile the TypeScript before using it with Node.js, which complicates things (slightly) — using the compiler in your toolchain, using source maps to understand where errors in production occurred in the real code, etc.

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript translates itself to JavaScript. So unless you absolutely need typescript, you can keep writing JS.

Thus why take the headache of transpiling during compile time and increase your development effort.